# dyld message when launching commands as sudo

Tags: macos, command-line, sudo

When I launch a command from the shell as super user I always get back the following message:

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
```

I tried to unset all the `DYL***` variables and verify it with the `set` command, as suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58442/mountain-lion-sudo-annoying-message). However it doesn't fixed my problem.

I'm running 10.8.2 with Xcode 4.5 and the command line tools updated today.

Please find below my `.profile`, I don't have a `.bash_profile`

```
# Git
 [ -f ~/.git-bash-completion.sh ] && . ~/.git-bash-completion.sh

# define colors and default command line
# h is the host name, w the complete path (W for only the current dir)
export PS1="\h:\w$ "

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad

export CPATH=/opt/local/include:/usr/local/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:/usr/local/lib
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH

# Homebrew
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH"

# ROS
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/wxPython/bin:$PATH
# The line below is commnted because it is imported with rosjava
# If you want to remove rosjava, uncomment it in order to use ros-fuerte
source ~/Software/ros/fuerte/ros-stacks/setup.bash
# source /Users/luca/Software/ros-java/setup.bash
export ROS_HOSTNAME=luca-macbook
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:~/Software/ros-stacks:~/Development/
export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=osx:homebrew

export SVN_EDITOR="/usr/bin/nano"

alias GoToPhdRoot="cd ~/Documents/University/PhD"
alias Smultron="open -a Smultron\ 4"
alias MakeBuildDir="mkdir build && cd build"
function UpdateAndBuildPdf() { 
    svn up && pdflatex "$1" && bibtex "$1" && pdflatex "$1" && rm "$1.aux" && rm "$1.bbl" && rm "$1.blg" && rm "$1.log" && Open "$1.pdf" 
}
```

To be noticed that also if I comment the line in which I export `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` the problem persists.

N.B. I don't have Asepsis installed.

Comment: Do you run Asepsis?

Comment: No, I don't! I found some posts where they said that the problem is related to Asepsis, but I don't even know it!

Comment: haha ok fair enough. I had the same problem and Asepsis was the issue, only reason I asked. I would edit the question to say that you dont use it.

Comment: can you please paste in your .bash_profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the warning is generated by the line

```
source ~/Software/ros/fuerte/ros-stacks/setup.bash
```

It is a line needed if you have installed [ROS](http://www.ros.org/).

Commenting the line fixes the problem. However ROS cannot work without this line.

Comment: Your problem isn't really fixed. This shell script is buggy, and around a very important stuff: dynamic libraries and setuid binaries. You should try to fix it and report the bug to its author.